# Make div scrollable is not scrolling in div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a specific `div` scrollable without making the entire page scroll. There are different elements in the page. The scroll div will not have a defined height, but its height should be based on its contents. Here's the layout:

[image]

I tried many things:

- adding overflow: auto/scroll to the scroll div and giving it a 100% height
- made the scroll div an absolute position

Nothing seems to work. How can I make an inner div scrollable without giving it a height in px?

Comment: "The scroll div will not have a defined height, but its height should be based on its contents" that means the content will never exceed the height. So the scroll will never appear because the height will increase as long as the content increases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some rule to impose a fixed or max-height on the element to ensure it hits a point where it wants to scroll. Then you can add an `overflow-y: scroll` style. An example with box 3:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 15vw);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 25vh);
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: end;
}

.box {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 150%;
}

.item1 {
  grid-column: 1 / 5;
}

.item2 {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  grid-row: 2 / 4;
}

.item3 {
  grid-column: 3 / 5;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box item1">One</div>
    <div class="box item2">Two</div>
    <div class="box item3">
      Three Three Three Three Three Three Three Three Three 
    </div>
    <div class="box item4">Four</div>
    <div class="box item5">Five</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to scroll the inside-div, the height of the inside-div needs to be defined, like here:

```css
.div-outside {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #FF2424;
}
.div-inside {
  position: static;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%; /* <--- Defined height needed for scrolling */
  background-color: #3D24FF;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-outside"><div class="div-inside">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div></div>
```

If the height of the inside-div is not defined, the inside-div grows with its content/text, like here:

```css
.div-outside {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #FF2424;
}
.div-inside {
  position: static;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 30%;
  background-color: #3D24FF;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-outside"><div class="div-inside">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div></div>
```